# How do I visually fake 4-space tabs in a 2-space project in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, tab-size

I've been working in 4-space tab codebases for nearly 2 decades, and recently started a new job where the codebase is all 2-space tabs and it's visually impossible for me to follow the structure of the code by looking at it.

**I'm not trying to change the actual tab size in code**, but I would love if there was a way to make VSCode display 2-space tabs *as if they were 4*. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If it's in a repository like git, have you thought of using triggers for check out and commit? Or wrapping the relevant commands with your own which pre/post-process the files into the desired format?

Comment: just configure the tab size in the settings, you can display a tab in any size you want, if your team mates want to view it in 2-space and you in 10-space it stays the same single tab, if you have to use 2 spaces you can use an extension I made [Indent Whitespace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-indentWhitespace), don't speak about 2-space tabs but 2-space indent, you don't use TAB characters to indent